# How can I discover WPF resources defined in another assembly?

Tags: wpf, styles

I'm writing some extension modules for a WPF Composite application supplied by another vendor.  The application is themed, and gives users the option to select from a number of themes which will change the appearance of the entire applications, including any custom modules that register themselves with the theme manager appropriately.

I really want my custom extensions to look like an integrated component, so I'm trying to use only styles defined as resources within the main application. As I'm still learning the nuances of XAML, I'm styling more by trial and error.

I'm wondering if there's a way of 'discovering' what styles are available in a different assembly. Here is an example of what I'm currently doing.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <common:DesignTimeResourceDictionary Source="/Vendor.Desktop.WPFCommon;component/themes/generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Border 
    Background="{DynamicResource LightGradientBackgroundBrush}"
    Margin="0"
    >
```

The `LightGradientBackgroundBrush` is defined in the vendors assemblies. By including the above `ResourceDictionary`, the style is present during design time, and the brush isn't underlined in the XAML editor.

Can I find what other styles are defined? I'm only aware of that style because it was mentioned in passing in a sample provided by the vendor.

Edit:

I'm aware of a BAML add-in for reflector, but it doesn't work with reflector 7 unless it has been recompiled/patched. Someone has already done that [here though](http://forums.reflector.net/questions/217/baml-add-in).

I was hoping there was a better solution though. Intellisense for styles would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a Reflector add-in for [viewing BAML resources](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BamlViewer) that worked well for that. But I haven't used Reflector in a while since Redgate crashed the party. It may not work with the current version.

Comment: there is a patched version of the BAML plugin for Reflector version 7 here: http://forums.reflector.net/questions/217/baml-add-in

Answer (score 0):

You know where your resource dictionary is so you should be able to load it up in code and enumerate over the available resources. This will at least give you an idea of what's available.

See this link:  http://blogs.claritycon.com/leeroth/2009/05/20/load-xaml-resource-dictionaries-at-runtime/

Enumerate over the Keys property and use the item property to access the resources. You can get as detailed as you want, but at the very least you should be able to spit out the resource names.

Comment: I quite like this answer, as it doesn't involve tools you need to buy, and plugins you need to patch. However, I've already got reflector and installing the pre-patched plugin sorted me out. Don't know why you were downvoted though. Bit harsh considering this will be the answer for the majority of people that don't already have reflector.